# Compute the Relative Error: which value is reference?

Tags: statistics

I have a question about a task I am trying to complete. I have created a code to produce a determinant of a 100x100 matrix. Now I want to compute the relative error between my solution and the solution obtained using

```
numpy.linalg.det.
```

So I know that the relative error is calculated by

```
(x - x_0)/x
```

where x is the absolute value and x_0 is the approximation. My question is what is the absolute value and what is the approximation, my code I have generated or using `numpy.linalg.det`

Both my answer and using `numpy.linalg.det` are almost equal.

Comment: can you also share your code snippet?

Comment: You mean to say, which of the two calculations do you hold as the standard? I'd say, use the numpy.linalg solution. But it matters not if they are near equal.

Comment: They are both approximations most likely, but I would treat the numpy solution as the standard simply because a lot of people have invested time and power into the library.

Comment: okay that's what I was thinking, use numpy.linalg as my x value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The experimental subject is your implementation; the NumPy solution is considered the reference value.  Thus

```
x = value from numpy
x_0 = value from your code
```

Think in terms of experimental design.